# Why can't I connect to my COM objects events after creation?

Tags: javascript, com, events, wsh

I have written a COM object using C++.

Creating the object and connecting to its events works fine if I do them both at the same time (Javascript):

```
var obj = WScript.CreateObject("SomeCOMClass.Object", "event_");
```

However the following generates this error (msdn): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7tya2wc(VS.85).aspx.

```
var obj = WScript.CreateObject("SomeCOMClass.Object");
WScript.ConnectObject(obj, "event_");
```

The error description page does not describe why I cannot connect to already created objects. I would like to be able to connect to created objects because I plan on returning objects from various C++ COM functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an old blog post by Eric Lippert describing this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2005/02/15/373330.aspx

Essentially, he says you need your objects to implement `IProvideClassInfo` or `IProvideMultipleClassInfo` in order for WScript to harvest type info about the outgoing (callback) interfaces, so it can set up a matching handler.